# How can I open a WinForm multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried opening a second form using a button on my main form, but when I close the second window, I can't open it again.

I added the following code to my main form:

```
settings_window secondForm = new settings_window();
private void settings_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secondForm.Show();
}
```

But when I try to open the second form named settings_window the second time, I get the following error: System.ObjectDisposedException.

I found the following code to fix this but I don't know where to place it:

```
private void settings_window_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    e.Cancel = true;    // Do not close the form.
}
```

Comment: Change this line `settings_window secondForm = new settings_window();` to `settings_window secondForm;` and then insert this line `secondForm = new settings_window();` above `secondForm.Show();`

Comment: First of all : [Naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions) ;D Then: it is an event Handler. It needs to go in your "settings_window" form code-behind. BUT: You need it to be registered. So, the easiest way is to go into the Designer, then in the properties pane switch to "events" and double click the FormClosing one. It will add the stub of code and register the handler, then you only have to populate it with the body of that handler you found. (It will make sense if you follow the instructions in VS)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid storing references of Forms and use a simple generic method that shows a Form when an instance of it already exists or creates a new one (and shows it) when none has been created before:

```
private void ShowForm<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    T? f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault();
    if (f is null) {
        f = new T();
        f.FormClosing += F_FormClosing;
    }
        
    f.Show();
    BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal));

    void F_FormClosing(object? sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        (sender as Form)?.Hide();
    }
}
```

When you need it, call as `ShowForm<SomeFormClass>()`, e.g.,

```
ShowForm<settings_window>()
```

Note:

- This code uses a local method to subscribe to the `FormClosing` event.
  You can use a standard method, in case this syntax is not available.
- `BeginInvoke()` is used to defer the `FormWindowState.Normal` assignment. This is used only in the case you minimize a Form, then right-click on its icon in the TaskBar and select `Close Windows` from the Menu. Without deferring this assignment, the minimized Form wouldn't show up again.
- When the starting Form closes, all other Forms close as well
- This code supposes `nullable` is enabled (e.g., see `object? sender`). If nullable is disabled or you're targeting .NET Framework, remove it (e.g., change in `object sender`)

Answer (score 0):

Is `secondForm` a private field of the main form class?
It should work then.

Alternative solution is to show it as as modal - `ShowDialog()`

Also if you want to save some data in your second form, just use some data initialization from constructor, then saving to first/parent form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a new instance of the form each time you want to open it. It will create a new instance of the settings_window form each time the button is clicked.

```
private void settings_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new instance of the form
    settings_window secondForm = new settings_window();
    secondForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: I'm troubled by this answer. Presumably, the purpose of the settings form is to keep track of the settings, and if you create a brand new instance of it every time you show it, wouldn't the settings always return to their default values? The Microsoft documentation for [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) is pretty specific about how a _member_ `Form` can have `ShowDialog` called repeatedly because the `Handle` is not destroyed when applied in this manner. It's designed for this exact scenario.

Comment: @IVSoftware OP has not provided such info in question. Just asked for opening closing multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows a class that you have named `settings_window`, which gives us a hint about what its intended use might be. In general, for a form that behaves "like" a settings window, that you can call multiple times using the same instance, you can declare a *member* variable using this pattern:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Provide some means, like a menu or button, to show 'secondForm'
        settingsMenu.Click += onClickSettingsMenu;
        // Dispose the settings_form when the MainForm does.
        Disposed += (sender, e) => secondForm.Dispose();
    }
    // By instantiating it here, its public default or persisted 
    // properties are immediately available, for example even 
    // while the main form constructs and loads the initial view.
    settings_window secondForm = new settings_window();

    private void onClickSettingsMenu(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(DialogResult.OK.Equals(secondForm.ShowDialog()))
        {
            // Apply actions using the properties of secondForm
        }
    }
}
```

This is suitable for any form when you want to:

- Repeatedly show and hide the form (e.g. a "Settings" form where the user can change the options multiple times).
- Retrieve the default or the persisted properties of the form from the outset *even if it's never been shown*.
- Use any of the form's public properties (e.g. `GameLevel`, `SortType` etc.) at any given moment while the app is running, even if the form isn't currently visible.
- Display the form [modally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.modal?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) meaning that "no input (keyboard or mouse click) can occur except to objects on the modal form".

The reason it works is that calling `ShowDialog` (unlike calling `Show`) intentionally does *not* dispose the window handle, and this is to support of this very kind of scenario. The app is then responsible for disposing the resource when the app closes.

The Microsoft documentation for [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) explains how this works.

> Unlike non-modal forms, the Close method is not called by the .NET Framework when the user clicks the close form button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

Comment: [Clone or browse](https://github.com/IVSoftware/reeopen-dialog-00) working minimal example.