# How can I set last selected item as default for a combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set the last selected item from a combobox as its default, meaning when I close this form and reopen it, the combobox shows and selects the last selected item again.

I have tried to save the `SelectedIndex` as an INT and use it like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    combobox1.SelectedIndex = Number;
}
```

But still, combobox always selecting the first item when I reopen the form.

Comment: where do you re-initialize the combobox items after reopening?

Comment: You probably want to store the last selection in User Settings

Comment: If **1** `Form1` is the _main_ form and you want to reopen the app and have the combo box where you left it (User Settings) you may find this answer helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61978765/5438626. But if **2**  `Form1` is a popup dialog that may be opened and closed multiple times from a 'parent' form then this answer might be closer to what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/75009730/5438626.

Comment: What is `Number`? Where and when do you set it? I suspect you can hardly set it before you call the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store this in the user settings provided by Visual Studio.
*Right-click on your project in visual studio and select Properties -> Settings.*
Add an item in the table such as defaultNumber set its type to `int` and scope user.

Make sure to add **"using YourProjectName.Properties"** at the top.

Then inside your form closing event write a code to save this setting.

```
Settings.Default.defaultNumber = combobox1.SelectedIndex;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

and in your form load event you should write

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = Settings.Default.defaultNumber;
```